# Match url only if it contains certain query parameters regex

Tags: regex, pcre

Hi i am looking for a regex that matches the url only if it contains
`a=anything` `b=anything` `c=anything`

`example.com?a=anything` => matches

`example.com?a=anything&b=anything` => matches

`example.com?b=any&c=any` => matches

`example.com?a=anything&d=anything` => not matches as `d` (unknown) was included

`example.com?e=anything` => not matches as `e` (unknown) was included

So url should only contain any permutation of `a` `b` and `c` and ignore the url when it contains any other query param

i came up with this until now `/\?(a|b|c)=[0-9]*&?/g`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use this regex in PCRE to match such URLs:

```sh
^[^\s?]+\?([abc]=[^&\n]*)(?:&(?1))*$
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/aCYmVL/1)

**RegEx Details:**

- `^`: Start
- `[^\s?]+`: Match 1+ of any characters that are not whitespaces and not `?`
- `\?`: Match a `?` to start query string
- `([abc]=[^&\n]*)`: Match a query parameter with names as `a` or `b` or `c`. Capture this in group #1
- `(?:&(?1))*`: Match 0 or more such query parameters by recursing capture group #1
- `$`: End

PS: This is by no means an all-purpose regex to match URLs.

Comment: can you please explain `(?:&(?1))*` a little bit more

Comment: `(?:...)` is a non-capturing group. `&` matches literal `&` character and `(?1)` matches same subpattern as in capture group #1

Comment: PCRE is not supported by javascript. how can we acheive this in javascript

Comment: But you tagged your question as `PCRE`

Comment: For Javascript use: `/^[^\s?]+\?[abc]=[^&\n]*(?:&[abc]=[^&\n]*)*$/`

Comment: Still the pcre pattern is an elegant solution ++